# help with exercise of differential equations(Rafael Iório)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

maybe someone could help me prove the uniqueness of the solution of the following problem:

\begin{equation*}
  \left\lbrace
  \begin{array}{l}
  \partial_x^2u-u=0,  \ (x,y)\in \mbox{R}^{2}\qquad 
  \\u(0,y)=f(y),\ y\in \mbox{ R}\qquad
  \\\partial_x u(0,y)=g(y),\ y\in \mbox{ R}\qquad
  \end{array}
  \right.  
 \\\ where \ u \in \mbox{ C}^{2}(R^{2})\qquad 
  y \ \ f,g \in \mbox{C}^{2}(R)\qquad 
\end{equation*}

I found the solution and my teacher told me that it is the next:
 \begin{equation*}  
  \begin{array}{l}
 u(x,y)=f(y)\cosh(x)+g(y)\sinh(x),  \ (x,y)\in \mbox{ RxR}\qquad  
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}
Someone please help I have two weeks and already noce what else to do. 
thanks

Comment: something tells me that it is $\partial_{xx}u - u = 0$ and not $\partial_x u^{2} - u =0$?